# Converting Weeknumber Fields into Rows

Tags: sql

I have a table that is layed out as follows :
Code,Year, Wk1Val, Wk2Val, Wk3Val, Wk4Val  etc to to Wk52Val.

Is there SQL to show the data as follows, without having to do 52 Case statements :

Code, Year, Week, Value

Comment: I guess, you are talking about unpivot

Comment: which database are you using `mysql` or `mssql`?

Comment: @lucumt I am using mssql

Comment: Having a sample of the data would help

Comment: Currently looks something like this :
Code,Year,Wk1,Wk2,Wk3,Wk4

4000,2022,10000,12000,11000,15000

4100,2022,3000,1000,5000,4000

4200,2022,20000,5000,15000,12000

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNPIVOT` with `REPLACE` functions. Be sure to add all **52** week columns to the `UNPIVOT` `IN` portion of the query.

```
SELECT 
  u.Code, 
  u.Year, 
  REPLACE(REPLACE(u.Weeks, 'Wk', ''), 'Val', '') AS Weeks,
  u.Value
FROM test
UNPIVOT
(
  Value FOR Weeks IN (Wk1Val, Wk2Val, Wk3Val, Wk4Val, Wk52Val)
) AS u;
```

Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/KUKgnVdV?hide=28).

**Input:**

| Code | Year | Wk1Val | Wk2Val | Wk3Val | Wk4Val | Wk52Val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022 | 5000 | 15000 | 9000 | 4000 | 1000 |
| 2 | 2022 | 900 | 3200 | 7000 | 8500 | 9500 |
| 3 | 2022 | 3500 | 7800 | 10000 | 6200 | 5600 |

**Output:**

| Code | Year | Weeks | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022 | 1 | 5000 |
| 1 | 2022 | 2 | 15000 |
| 1 | 2022 | 3 | 9000 |
| 1 | 2022 | 4 | 4000 |
| 1 | 2022 | 52 | 1000 |
| 2 | 2022 | 1 | 900 |
| 2 | 2022 | 2 | 3200 |
| 2 | 2022 | 3 | 7000 |
| 2 | 2022 | 4 | 8500 |
| 2 | 2022 | 52 | 9500 |
| 3 | 2022 | 1 | 3500 |
| 3 | 2022 | 2 | 7800 |
| 3 | 2022 | 3 | 10000 |
| 3 | 2022 | 4 | 6200 |
| 3 | 2022 | 52 | 5600 |